# How do get a 2D sprite to face the camera in a 3D unity game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, sprite, helper, nlp-question-answering

I've been trying to get it to work but most of the codes are either outdated or doesn't work can anyone help i need a code for unity 2021 ?

I tried finding some codes but they are pretty old like from 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "billboard" in computer graphics refers to an object that always faces the camera. You can try a billboard component, like so:

```
public class Billboard : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform cam;
    private void Start() {
        cam = Camera.main.transform;
    }
    void LateUpdate() {
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + cam.forward);
    }
}
```

A follow camera behaviour should always be implemented in the `LateUpdate` because it tracks objects that might have moved inside the `Update`. Also if your sprite is inside a canvas make sure its in world's space, so that it is a 3D world object and it can rotatute. Canvas space is an option in the canvas component itself.